# How does the test_isEven3 function work in this program?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

```
import unittest
def isEven(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False 

class TestIsEvenMethod(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_isEven1(self):
        self.assertEqual(isEven(5),False)

    def test_isEven2(self):
        self.assertEqual(isEven(10),True)

    def test_isEven3(self):
        with self.assertRaises(AttributeError) as a:
            x = self.isEven("hello")
            self.assertEqual(AttributeError, str(a.exception))  
            print(x)
unittest.main()
print(isEven(43))
```

I tried reading about it but I couldn't find clear answers. Could someone provide an explanation on how the `test_isEven3` function works and why `AttributeError` is being compared with `a.exception`?

Answer (score -1):

import unittest
def isEven(x):
    if x%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

class TestIsEvenMethod(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_isEven1(self):
        self.assertEqual(isEven(5),False)

```
def test_isEven2(self):
    self.assertEqual(isEven(10),True)

def test_isEven3(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as a:
        x = self.isEven("hello")
        self.assertEqual(TypeError, str(a.exception))  
        print(x)
```

unittest.main()

Comment: Question is about: expecting a explanation about `test_isEven3` funciton.